# BizTalk 2010: Access Context In Map

Tags: mapping, biztalk, biztalk-2010

This could be a very basic question, but hopefully someone will be able to answer it.

I am receiving messages (HL7) using a custom receive pipeline. Inside my custom pipeline, I am promoting properties into the context. I have set up a map where I need to access these properties. However, I would like to access these properties on the send side. The reason why it needs to be on the send side is because I am attaching my map to the send port, so I assume that the message will have already hit the MessageBox and will be mapped on the send side. Hopefully that makes sense...

I know that there are a few 3rd party tools I can use, but I was hoping that there's a simple functoid, or some code I can enter in a scripting functoid that will access the context for me.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: I ended up using an orchestration in order to access the context properties and then use the transform shape to perform the mapping within the orchestration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, indeed [a C# functoid](http://contextaccessor.codeplex.com/) that allows access to context properties but it seems to only work with maps on a *Receive Port* or inside an *Orchestration*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Context Accessor Functiod to do this... Combine it's pipeline component with yours and it should work... Beware it should be handled within the same thread...

http://contextaccessor.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible. However, I had a similar requirement to access message context properties and I was able to populate a message with the context properties in an orchestration thanks to

[Greg.Forsythe's excellent instructions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/c7328eec-6b66-409c-82af-788920bf64b4)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation to access the context properties to get the filename property in the my map. I did the below steps without using any external functoids. Hope this helps someone

Steps:

1. create a new schema say "FileSchema" 
   FileNode(rootNode)
   -FileName (fieldElement)
2. Click the schema and in the properties target namespace - clear the namespace.
3. make the FileName property distinguished. Rt.Click FileName and show promotions and add FileName to Distinguished property tab.
4. In your target schema, add the field FileName. for me I added it to a SQL schema, since I need the filename for every row in the database
5. In your orchestration, use the message assignment shape and type the below

// create a variable varFileXML of type System.XML.XMLDocument

// I'm creating a xml same like the file schema and loading that to the XML variable and then assigning that to the Message of type FileSchema

```
varFileXML = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
varFileXML.LoadXml("<FileNode><FileName>FileName_0</FileName></FileNode>");
Msg_FileSchema = varFileXML;
```

//Get the FileName to a variable of string type

```
varFileName = Msg_FlatFileSchema(FILE.ReceivedFileName);
varFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(varFileName);
```

//Access the filename property from the message and assign the variable to that

```
Msg_File.FileName = varFileName;
```

6. Now that we got the FileName in to the message you can use that in mapping to your target schema
7. I used a transform shape to create a new inline map with source as your target schema and fileschema together and the destination as the target schema.I mapped the filename from the fileschema to my target schema the filename property

this is one of the many ways to get the context property. Hope it helps

thanks & regards

Silam